# Passing JQuery variable to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code that fetches time differences in UTC, but it outputs straight to HTML. I want to store the results of the function to use later, such that in the example below, `r1` and `r2` stores the result of `responseText` based on the 'timezone' passed. How can I do this?

```html
<!-- <input type="button" value="Get Current Time" onclick="getTime()"> -->
<p id="responseText"></p>
```

```js
function getTime(timezone) {
  $.get("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/" + timezone, null, function(data) {
    $("#responseText").text(data.raw_offset)
  })
};

var r1 = getTime("Asia/Kolkata");
var r2 = getTime("Europe/Copenhagen");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, is to use [`async/await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) and wait for the async `$.get()` method to return the result and then store the result in two variables. But, for that also, you'll need an async function.

```js
async function getTime( timezone ){

  const data = await $.get( "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/" + timezone );
  return data.raw_offset;

}

// You need to place you main application code in an async function since you will be `awaiting` for the result of two other async functions:
async function init(){

  let r1 = await getTime("Asia/Kolkata");
  let r2 = await getTime("Europe/Copenhagen");
  console.log( r1, r2 );

}

init();
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/rNVjJVW?editors=0011)

---

Alternatives:

- You can drop jQuery and use `fetch()` as `Traveling Tech Guy` proposes.
- You can use `Promises` instead of `async/await`, but that will make the code a lot harder to read and write

Comment: This is very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await`, `async` and `fetch` to get what you need. This code works:

```
<html>
<script>
async function getTime(timezone = '') {
  try {
    let response = await fetch("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/" + timezone);
    let result = await response.json();
    // $("#responseText").text(result.raw_offset);
    return result.raw_offset;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
    return null;
  }
}

(async function() {
  let diff = await getTime('Asia/Kolkata');
  console.log(diff)
}());
</script>
</html>
```

Notice that if timezone is not passed to the function, we set it to an empty string, to avoid garbage (which you may get in your original implementation).